# Incremental ETL using Glue

Tags: etl, aws-glue

Need help in processing incremental files.

Scenario: Source team is creating file in every 1hr in s3 (hrly partitioned). I would like to process in every 4hr. The Glue etl will read the s3 files (partitioned hrly) and process to store in different s3 folders.

Note : Glue ETL is called from airflow.

Question How can I make sure that I only process the incremental files ( let’s say 4 files in each execution)?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a use case for [Bookmarks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-continuations.html)

> For example, your ETL job might read new partitions in an Amazon S3
> file. AWS Glue tracks which partitions the job has processed
> successfully to prevent duplicate processing and duplicate data in the
> job's target data store.